# Show that $\{x \in X: \sup_{i} f_i(x) > r \}= \bigcup_{i} \{x \in X : f_i(x) >r \}.$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, sequence-of-function

> Show that $\{x \in X: \sup_{i} f_i(x) > r \}= \bigcup_{i} \{x \in X : f_i(x) >r \}.$

For $x \in \bigcup_{i} \{x \in X : f_i(x) >r \} \implies$ $f_i(x)>r$ for some $i$. Now by the definition of the supremum $\sup_i f_i(x) \ge f_i(x) > r$ so $x \in \{x \in X: \sup_{i} f_i(x) > r \} $.

The other side is hard. If $x \in \{x \in X: \sup_{i} f_i(x) > r \} $. Now this says that $\sup_i f_i(x) > r$. What I need know is that $\sup_i f_i(x) \ge f_i(x)$ for all $i$, but not neccessarily that $f_i(x) > r$. I don’t remember very well the properties of the supremum, but wasn’t it that I could somehow ”squeeze” something in between $\sup_i f_i(x) > r$?

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of supreme, if $t\in \{x \in X: \sup_{i} f_i(x) > r \}$ then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $j_{\epsilon}$ such that
$$
\sup_{i} f_{i}(t) \geq f_{j_{\epsilon}}(t)>\sup_{i}f_{i}(t)-\epsilon.
$$
If $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\left( \sup_{i} f_i(x) - r\right)>0$ then we have
\begin{align}
f_{j_{\epsilon}}(t)>& 
\sup_{i}f_{i}(t)-\epsilon
\\
=& 
\sup_{i}f_{i}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\left( \sup_{i} f_i(x) - r\right)
\\
=& 
\frac{1}{2}\sup_{i}f_{i}(t)+\frac{1}{2}r
\\
>& 
\frac{1}{2}r+\frac{1}{2}r
\\
=& 
r
\end{align}
Conclusion $f_{j_{\epsilon}}(t)>r$.
Then $t\in \{x \in X: f_{j_{\epsilon}}(x) > r \}$ and
$$
t\in \bigcup_{i} \{x \in X: f_i(x) > r \}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here, I assume $f_i$ maps $X$ either to $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ (and that in the former case $f_i(x)$ is bounded above for each $x$) so the neccessary suprema all exist. By definition,
$\sup_i f_i(x)$ is the least $s$ such that $s \ge f_n(x)$ for all $n$. Hence, if $x \in \{x \in X : \sup_i f_i(x) > r\}$, there is some $n$ such that $f_n(x) > r$ (otherwise $r \ge f_n(x)$ for all $n$, implying that $\sup_i f_i(x) \le r$). But then, for that $n$:
$$
x \in \{x \in X : f_n(x) > r\} \subseteq \bigcup_i\{x \in X : f_i(x) > r\}
$$

Comment: Sorry for misinformation. $f_i$ are maps from $X \to \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Do you really mean $\Bbb{R}^n$ where $n$ can be greater than $1$?  If so, what ordering are you using on $\Bbb{R}^n$? (However, the above proof doesn't depend on the ordering only on the existence of the suprema involved).

Comment: Ah sorry. The suprema isn’t well defined if $\Bbb R^n$. It should be $\Bbb R$...

Comment: OK - I added an extra bit to my comment: it doesn't really matter what the ordering is.

Comment: You seem to be using index $n$ and $i$ quite interchangeably. May I ask is how is $n$ used here?

Comment: I was using $i$ for the bound variables in $\sup_i$ and $\bigcup_i$ and $n$ for the free variables that crop up in the proof: read all the $n$s as $i$, if you are comfortable with two different uses of $i$ in one formula.